# Using R to extract specific column in Azure ML

Tags: r, azure, dataframe, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a forecasting causal model in Azure ML studio that determines an organization's hiring needs for every month for 2015. Since it is a causal model, I individually forecast all parameters for 2015 and supply them to my model.

One such factor is previous 9 months Hire value. It means that if I am forecasting a hire value for Jan-2015, the previous 9 month hire values will be considered (Dec - April 2014).

The following is my parameter set:

```
Year    Month   Factor A    Factor B    Factor C    Factor D    Prev. Month-1   Prev. Month-2   Prev. Month-3   Prev. Month-4   Prev. Month-5   Prev. Month-6   Prev. Month-7   Prev. Month-8   Prev. Month-9
```

Sample Input:

```
Year    Month   Factor A    Factor B    Factor C    Factor D    Prev. Month-1   Prev. Month-2   Prev. Month-3   Prev. Month-4   Prev. Month-5   Prev. Month-6   Prev. Month-7   Prev. Month-8   Prev. Month-9
2015    1       2           4           6           8           10              11              12              13              14              15              16              17              18
```

Once I run the model, I get the Forecasted hire (Score Labels) as my output:

```
Year    Month   Factor A    Factor B    Factor C    Factor D    Prev. Month-1   Prev. Month-2   Prev. Month-3   Prev. Month-4   Prev. Month-5   Prev. Month-6   Prev. Month-7   Prev. Month-8   Prev. Month-9   Score Labels
2015    1       2           4           6           8           10              11              12              13              14              15              16              17              18              19
```

For forecasting for February-2015, the forecasted value for January becomes Prev. Month-1 value.

```
Year    Month   Factor A    Factor B    Factor C    Factor D    Prev. Month-1   Prev. Month-2   Prev. Month-3   Prev. Month-4   Prev. Month-5   Prev. Month-6   Prev. Month-7   Prev. Month-8   Prev. Month-9
2015    1       2           4           6           8           10              11              12              13              14              15              16              17              18
2015    2       3           5           7           9           19              10              11              12              13              14              15              16              17
```

This becomes a bit tedious as I have to repeat it 12 times - one for each month. Can someone suggest how do I solve it using R script? Here is what I have written so far:

```
dataset <- maml.mapInputPort(1) 

previous <- 9
orig_names <- names(dataset)
n_rows <- dim(dataset)[1]

base <- 9
for (i in 1:previous) {
  dataset[(i+1):n_rows,base+i] <- dataset[1:(n_rows-i),base]
  dataset[1:i,base+i] <- dataset[1:i,base+i-1]
}

a <- -1:-previous
new_names <- paste("Prev. Month",a)
names(dataset) <- c(orig_names,new_names)

maml.mapOutputPort("dataset")
```

Thanks.

**Update 1**

I have managed to execute my model in a loop in Azure. For each iteration, I need to provide the input parameters (like for February).

Can someone help me on how to obtain the forecast under "Score Labels" and append that as a parameter under "Prev. Month-1" to my input for next month in R?

Comment: Can someone help? I am really struggling with R.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the data set?  I'm fairly certain I can solve this with sample data set and more clear goal.